# Как в Redmine изменить для трекера дату начала?

Tags: redmine

Создавая задачу ошибся датой начала... И вот как в системе Redmine изменить для трекера дату начала?

Comment: Администраторские права есть?

Comment: Да, есть права админа

Comment: Администрирование -> Трекеры меняйте там всё что нужно
Я так понимаю, дата начала появилась с плагином? У меня её просто нету